# Alsa playback delay

Tags: linux, audio, delay, playback, alsa

My alsa is configured with 
Buffer_size = 2048 and period_size  = 1024

I am using IMX6 board to board. I am running a binary in board which captures audio from analog input and multicasts. The Other board is running as a listener which receives the frames and using "snd_pcm_writei", the frame is written to the alsa.

Now there is delay in the playback for about 1min, after which starts to play continuously.
Iam not sure whether iam miising something.

The logs with snd_pcm_avail() after writing to the alsa is given below. Please provide your feedback.
What i suspect is, the frame is written to alsa but alsa doesnt playback and so the next frame is overwritten.

Log:

```
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:01.029202  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:02.030307  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:03.031376  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:04.032432  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:05.033494  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:06.034551  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:07.035603  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:08.036680  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
   (AVB Info)     01:29:09.037726  (Slave)               ==> Broken pipe
pcm avail val is :2048
pcm avail val is :-32
```

Comment: How are you synchronizing the sample clocks of the two devices?

Comment: We are setting the sampling rate through alsa in the code manually(44.1). Both the hardwares are same , I dont think there should be any deviation in the sampling freq

Comment: Without some mechanism to synchronize the clocks, the two devices run at different speeds. You have to measure the deviation and do resampling.